# How to plot by lookup table (dictionary)

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, matplotlib, seaborn

I want to plot values based on dictionary.

So, if I have this DataFrame:

```py
match_winners = pd.DataFrame({'match_id':[1,2,3,4,5,6],
                              'player_1':['Sarah', 'Gorge', 'Mike', 'Steve', 'Madlin', 'Ali'],
                              'player_2':['Mike', 'Ali', 'Madlin', 'Sarah', 'Gorge', 'Steve'],
                              'winner':['Sarah', 'Ali', 'Mike', 'Sarah', 'Gorge', 'Steve']})
```

and I also have this dictionary:

```
myDict = {'team_1': ['Sarah', 'Madlin', 'Gorge'],
          'team_2': ['Ali', 'Mike', 'Steve']}
```

I want `seaborn.countplot()` to plot the count of team_1, team_2 instead of the winner column directly.

here is the direct plot:

```
sb.countplot(data = match_winners, x = 'winner');
```

[The plot link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SrVq0.png)

Answer (score 0):

is there a better way than this ?

```
for idx, row in match_winners.iterrows():
    if  match_winners.loc[idx,'winner'] in myDict['team_1']:
        match_winners.loc[idx,'team_winner'] = 'team_1'
    elif match_winners.loc[idx,'winner'] in myDict['team_2']:
        match_winners.loc[idx,'team_winner'] = 'team_2'
```